# Android Image Gallery

Tags: android

I have an App which contains a gallery with images in a Gridview.
If I tap on one of the Images it opens up a view which shows the single image that I've selected. I can then switch between the images by sliding horizontally.
I have a text on the bottom and the image is above the text. If I now switch to landscape mode the text is shown on top of the image. What would be a nice way to present the text?

Thanks a lot!

This is the portrait mode:

[portrait mode http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/811/19327243.png](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/811/19327243.png)

And this the landscape mode:

[landscape mode http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/27/82311957.png](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/27/82311957.png)

So I would like to know where to position the image/text in landscape mode and how to style it (inside a box? on a black background? etc.)

Comment: I find your question a bit hard to comprehend. So, the text is hidden behind the image in portrait mode? Is that intended on your part in that case?
And what do you mean with "nice way to present the text"? Are you talking text styling, possible animation, positioning? If you could provide some more context we would be able to pinpoint your problem more thoroughly.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation! I have updated the question and added some screens and more explanation to my problem, so that it's easier to understand. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Sometimes it can be hard to explain thoroughly enough since you already know the problem inside and out. Now I think it's clear what you mean. Hope you get some nice suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the picture name on the bottom side of the picture in a separate layer with a transparent black background. In addition you can offer an option to hide or show the names.

Another interesting solution... show the description only if you swiping up the image. see the link

[Show description by swiping up image](http://littlebigdetails.com/post/32262080542/audium-swiping-down-on-any-album-cover-reveals)

Comment: Do you mean on the bottom side of the picture but still ON the picture or really on the bottom side with some padding?

Wow yes the swiping solution looks very nice! Do you have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Sorry I have no coding background for the swiping solution. 
The description could be in a separate layer above the picture. The picture can be displayed in full screen mode.